# SQRT decomposition 2D

Tags: c++, алгоритм, оптимизация

Есть площадь заданного размера, на ней указаны N точек, и даны их координаты. Нужно научиться быстро отвечать на запрос сколько точек  находится в квадрате. Моя идея заключается в том, чтобы поделить область на sqrt(N) * sqrt(N) меньших областей, преподсчетом решить задачу на них, по данной матрице построить матрицу частичных сумм, и в итоге просто после поступления запроса (координат квадрата) добавлять к подсчитанным точкам из маленьких квадратов, рассмотренные отдельно, вручную.
Что-то такое:

```
int sqrt_count = std::ceil(std::sqrt(points_num));
int rect_size = std::ceil(lim / sqrt_count);
matrix2d ppr = matrix2d(sqrt_count, std::vector<int>(sqrt_count, 0)); // points_per_rect
for (int i = 0; i < points_num; ++i)
{
    ++ppr[points[i].X / rect_size][points[i].Y / rect_size];
}

matrix2d blocks = matrix2d(sqrt_count + 1, std::vector<int>(sqrt_count + 1, 0));
for (int i = 1; i < sqrt_count; ++i)
{
    for (int j = 1; j < sqrt_count; ++j)
    {
        blocks[i][j] = blocks[i][j - 1] + blocks[i - 1][j] - blocks[i - 1][j - 1] + ppr[i - 1][j - 1];
    }
}
```

Но проблема с которой я столкнулся, это то что я не пойму, как теперь мне узнать, какие конкретно точки принадлежат какому из этих квадратов. Допустим поступает запрос, где используются два цельных маленьких квадрата, и один наполовину. Два цельных я могу просто добавить не считая, а для того что наполовину, мне нужно проверить какие точки из него входят, а какие нет. 
Хранить отдельно те точки что я добавляю для каждого квадратика очень накладно. В обычной одномерной sqrt декомпозиции все просто, ведь там преобразовывается индекс, а как быть здесь?

Comment: [Квадродерево](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Raphael_Finkel/publication/220197855_Quad_Trees_A_Data_Structure_for_Retrieval_on_Composite_Keys/links/0c9605273bba2ece7b000000.pdf) же. Построите по точкам, а потом по региону (квадрату) найдёте все точки за O(logN). Я писал реализацию для региона круга, для квадрата ещё проще.

Comment: Да скорее всего, если не выйдет в итоге оптимизировать, то придется использовать квадродерево.

Answer (score 0):

Точка с координатами `x,y` попадает в ячейку с индексами `[y / cellHeight], [x / cellWidth]`   -  это уже сделано

А относительно хранения - трёхмерный вектор должен содержать векторы точек в  каждой ячейке, в другом месте их хранить уже не нужно. При обработке каждой точки добавляем её в вектор с указанными индексами.

Вот [пример похожей задачи на Delphi](https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/441-fast-way-to-find-points-near-a-given-point/?tab=comments#comment-3491)

```
Grid: array[0..63, 0..63] of TArray<Integer>;
```

хранит индексы точек, но ничего не мешает держать там сами точки

Comment: Да, к такому решению я тоже приходил, но ячеек у нас sqrt(N) * sqrt(N), что значит матрица занимает линейный объем, и вектор который она хранит, выходит тоже N в длину, ведь вполне может быть что все точки попадут в одну ячейку, и выходит квадратичная память, при ограничениях задачи это слишком много.

Comment: В таком случае нужны cпециальные структуры данных, равномерно распределяющие точки по ячейками разного размера - например, kd-tree

Comment: Тоже думал о нем, но задача описана как такая, что решается двумерной sqrt декомпозицией.

Comment: Минуточку - почему квадратичная память, когда она как раз линейная! Ведь если все точки в одной ячейке, то только один вектор длинный, остальные нулевой  длины, суммарно N

Comment: Как линейная? еще раз, двумерная матрица, которая есть копия разбиения плоскости, а в ней вектор точек, вектор размера N, сама матрица тоже

Comment: Двумерная матрица sqrt(N) * sqrt(N) даёт N векторов третьего уровня. Их суммарная длина N

Comment: Да, но при реализации на c++ в любом случае они будут все приведены к одной длине

Comment: Как это? Вектор - динамическая структура данных, у неё есть только постоянный оверхед на заголовок.

Comment: Ну на самом деле попробовать стоит, спасибо